# How to use google transtate and currency conversation api in angular 6?

Tags: angular, curry-currency-converter

I'm trying to use Google translate and a currency conversion API in my angular 2+ project.

I found that Google has stopped providing the currency conversion API. Do you know any API's like this?

Besides that, there is no document for Google Translate API with angular 2+. Does anyone have a solution or document to solve this problem?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Hey @NNQ-Company. Can you share some code or be much more specific in your question regarding your issue? What possible solutions have you tried that did not work? Have you looked at similar questions to try to solve your issue?

Comment: Hi @hitautodestruct, thanks for your answer, I have not started this project. I just want to ensure that there are some api to support this.

Comment: then maybe you need to research this before asking a question. SO is for answering questions that have a technical nature and are not overly opinionated. Sadly, you can't use this platform as a forum. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular pipe for the currency conversion instead of API, Let me know if you want help with pipe.

Comment: Hi @Roshan Singh, Thanks for your answer, 
Because I want to have a widget to convert currency, this has to get the new rate of each currency so that users can convert with the latest rate? Is angular pipe can solve that?